# unable to npm install globalization with ionic 2.2.0, Unmet dependencies

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, globalization

I am trying to install the "globalization" plugin, in order to access .getPreferredLanguage() in my ionic 2 app, but I get this UNMET DEPENDENCY error.

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization --savePlugin "cordova-plugin-globalization" already installed on android.

Plugin "cordova-plugin-globalization" already installed on ios.

Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-globalization" to config.xml

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/globalizationboardline@1.0.0 /home/louisro/Documents/mobileApps/BoardLine/ionic_version
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@*
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0
├── @ionic-native/globalization@3.4.4 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.0.1

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic-native/globalization@3.4.4 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic-native/globalization@3.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic-native/globalization@3.4.4 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic/cloud-angular@0.4.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0-rc.0 <2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic/cloud-angular@0.4.0 requires a peer of rxjs@>=5.0.0-beta.0 but none was installed.
```

and

```
$ ionic info

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

**EDIT** I am adding package.json code here:
package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.1",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^3.4.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/pouchdb": "5.4.28",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.8.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "pouchdb": "^6.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "@types/cordova": "0.0.34",
    "@types/cordova-ionic": "0.0.29",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Boane: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: can you put the code of `package.json` file?

Comment: Yes, here it is @Sampath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this `"ionic-native": "2.8.1",`.You have to remove it , in order to only have one line for ionic-native: `"@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",`.
After that run `npm i`

Comment: Sorry @Sampath, I pasted the wrong file...now I fixed that in the question, can you please re check ?

Comment: please see the **Update** section on my post above.

Comment: ok thanks, did you see just above that there's the line: "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.1" ? should I only keep one unique line for "@ionic-native/core" ?

Comment: Oh.. Anyway you must remove `ionic-native": "2.8.1"`. and run `npm i`.You cannot keep both modules.

Comment: I just removed `ionic-native": "2.8.1"` and now it works! Thanks. Do you think I should upate to "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4" ? or the line I have "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.1" is ok ?

Comment: I think you have to upgrade according to your file.you can see that there are number of plugins which are using `3.4.4`.`geolocation`,`google-analytics` and etc.Either you have to downgrade those to `3.4.1` or upgrade all to `3.4.4`.